# Storing the data in "Memo" of block chain transaction

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, dapp

1. Can I store large size of data such as MP3 in Memo?
   Are there any implementation examples?
2. To store the data or any comments in Memo, should I send some amount of EOS?
   Can I store the data without sending EOS?

Answer (score 2):

As per https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/eosio.token/src/eosio.token.cpp

maximum memo size is 256 bytes so you can't store an mp3 as a memo.